# Linux QEMU - Guest can SSH to Host, but Host to Guest

Tags: ssh, networking, qemu

I've been having some problems with Host-Guest networking via SSH. I've looked through many questions here as well as the Networking Documentation for QEMU (https://wiki.qemu.org/Documentation/Networking#How_to_get_SSH_access_to_a_guest), but have not been able to find an answer.

My guest QEMU instance is able to SSH into the host machine as normal. However, when I try to SSH into the QEMU instance from the host machine I get a `ssh_exchange_identification: read: Connection reset by peer` error.

Here is the command I use to boot QEMU:

```
qemu-system-aarch64 -M virt -m 32768 -cpu cortex-a72 \
  -kernel $VMLINUZ \
  -initrd $INITRD \
  -append 'root=/dev/vda2' \
  -drive if=none,file=$COW,format=qcow2,id=hd \
  -device virtio-blk-pci,drive=hd \
  -netdev user,id=mynet \
  -device virtio-net-pci,netdev=mynet \
  -nographic \
  -device e1000,netdev=net0 \
  -netdev user,id=net0,hostfwd=tcp::5555-:22
```

Once QEMU is booted, I try to SSH using the following command and get this output:

```
<*user*>@<*hostname*>:~$ ssh localhost -p 5555 -vvv
OpenSSH_7.6p1 Ubuntu-4ubuntu0.3, OpenSSL 1.0.2n  7 Dec 2017
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 19: Applying options for *
debug2: resolving "localhost" port 5555
debug2: ssh_connect_direct: needpriv 0
debug1: Connecting to localhost [127.0.0.1] port 5555.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /home/<*user*>/.ssh/id_rsa type 0
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/<*user*>/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/<*user*>/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/<*user*>/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/<*user*>/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/<*user*>/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/<*user*>/.ssh/id_ed25519 type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/<*user*>/.ssh/id_ed25519-cert type -1
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_7.6p1 Ubuntu-4ubuntu0.3
ssh_exchange_identification: read: Connection reset by peer
```

Any help with this is greatly appreciated!

Edit:

Both machines are running Ubuntu 18.04.

Host:

```
Linux trace5 5.0.0-37-generic #40~18.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Thu Nov 14 12:06:39 UTC 2019 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Guest:

```
Linux qemu-trace 5.2.0-050200-generic #201907072331 SMP Sun Jul 7 23:48:00 UTC 2019 aarch64 aarch64 aarch64 GNU/Linux
```

Guest is running `sshd`,

```
ps -ef | grep '[s]shd'
root 616 1 0 Dec11 ? 00:00:00 /usr/sbin/sshd -D
```

This is an excerpt of `/var/log/auth.log` on the Guest if it helps. I'm reading an authentication failure, but unsure what that means as the timestamps don't align with when my host was ssh-ing:

```
Dec 11 18:43:17 qemu-trace sshd[1547]: Server listening on 0.0.0.0 port 22.
Dec 11 18:43:17 qemu-trace sshd[1547]: Server listening on :: port 22.
Dec 11 18:43:17 qemu-trace sudo: pam_unix(sudo:session): session closed for user root
Dec 11 18:45:30 qemu-trace systemd-logind[610]: New seat seat0.
Dec 11 18:45:33 qemu-trace sshd[617]: Server listening on 0.0.0.0 port 22.
Dec 11 18:45:33 qemu-trace sshd[617]: Server listening on :: port 22.
Dec 11 18:46:18 qemu-trace login[620]: pam_unix(login:session): session opened for user trace by LOGIN(uid=0)
Dec 11 18:46:19 qemu-trace systemd-logind[610]: New session 1 of user trace.
Dec 11 18:46:19 qemu-trace systemd: pam_unix(systemd-user:session): session opened for user trace by (uid=0)
Dec 11 19:17:01 qemu-trace CRON[675]: pam_unix(cron:session): session opened for user root by (uid=0)
Dec 11 19:17:02 qemu-trace CRON[675]: pam_unix(cron:session): session closed for user root
Dec 11 19:20:13 qemu-trace systemd-logind[605]: New seat seat0.
Dec 11 19:20:17 qemu-trace sshd[616]: Server listening on 0.0.0.0 port 22.
Dec 11 19:20:17 qemu-trace sshd[616]: Server listening on :: port 22.
Dec 11 19:22:33 qemu-trace login[621]: pam_unix(login:auth): check pass; user unknown
Dec 11 19:22:33 qemu-trace login[621]: pam_unix(login:auth): authentication failure; logname=LOGIN uid=0 euid=0 tty=/dev/ttyAMA0 ruser= rhost=
Dec 11 19:22:37 qemu-trace login[621]: FAILED LOGIN (1) on '/dev/ttyAMA0' FOR 'UNKNOWN', Authentication failure
Dec 11 19:22:49 qemu-trace login[621]: pam_unix(login:session): session opened for user trace by LOGIN(uid=0)
Dec 11 19:22:49 qemu-trace systemd-logind[605]: New session 1 of user trace.
Dec 11 19:22:50 qemu-trace systemd: pam_unix(systemd-user:session): session opened for user trace by (uid=0)
```

Comment: Are you trying via passwords, or do you want to use public/private key pairs? Have you tried using the guest's hostname instead of port forwarding?

Comment: Just trying via passwords right now. I want to get it working before I do any public/private key stuff. Also trying to use the guest's hostname results in a: `ssh: Could not resolve hostname qemu-lab1: Name or service not known` error.

Comment: You'll need to add the hosts entries to /etc/hosts. When I setup ssh on my guests, all I did (besides the default install) was disable password authentication. Are your guests on the default NAT network? If so, you *should* be able to login directly, without using port forwarding.

Comment: Need information:
Host OS?
Guest OS?
pings from host to OS and OS to Host?
guest network is NAT/Bridge? & configuration?

Comment: @Chronos added version info as well as some `/var/log/auth.log` output. Guest network should have been configured with the QEMU command line above (ie. `-netdev user,id=mynet -device virtio-net-pci,netdev=mynet -device e1000,netdev=net0 -netdev user,id=net0,hostfwd=tcp::5555-:22)`. This is a fresh install of Aarch64 Ubuntu 18.04 on the Guest

Comment: "_Guest is running `sshd` as I have used it to SSH into Host_". If you are using `ssh` on the guest to connect to the host, then it has no bearing on whether or not the guest is running `sshd`. Please use `ps -ef | grep [s]shd` on the guest to confirm that it is running.

Comment: `<user>@<guest>:~$ ps -ef | grep sshd` yeilds: 
`root       616     1  0 Dec11 ?        00:00:00 /usr/sbin/sshd -D`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was able to find the issue; it was a problem with my QEMU command. New command to boot QEMU:

```
qemu-system-aarch64 -M virt -m 32768 -cpu cortex-a72 \
  -kernel $VMLINUZ \
  -initrd $INITRD \
  -append 'root=/dev/vda2' \
  -drive if=none,file=$COW,format=qcow2,id=hd \
  -device virtio-blk-pci,drive=hd \
  -netdev user,id=mynet \
  -device virtio-net-pci,netdev=mynet,hostfwd=tcp::2222-:22 \
  -nographic
```

And then I can SSH from the Host:

```
<user>@<host>:~$ ssh <host>@localhost -p 2222
<user>@localhost's password: 
Welcome to Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS (GNU/Linux 5.2.0-050200-generic aarch64)

 * Documentation:  https://help.ubuntu.com
 * Management:     https://landscape.canonical.com
 * Support:        https://ubuntu.com/advantage

Last login: Thu Dec 12 14:31:28 2019
<user>@<guest>:~$
```

Answer (score 0):

You've got an entry in `/etc/hosts.deny` that prevents the `ssh` login.

For example, this will deny inbound connection attempts for all services from all remote systems:

```
ALL : ALL
```

On my Debian system, the file `/var/log/auth.log` contains reasons for `ssh` having refused a login. There will be something similar on your guest. An entry corresponding to the `hosts.deny` example entry I've shown here looks something like this

```
Dec 11 22:54:40 vmguest sshd[30741]: refused connect from 192.168.1.2 (192.168.1.2)
```

Comment: Hello. Unfortunately, my `/etc/hosts.deny` file is empty. I have also changed the `/etc/hosts.allow` to include: `ALL : ALL` but neither seemed to work. I also do not see a refusal occur in the `/var/log/auth.log` file

Comment: @Tex4066 what's your guest OS? (`uname -a` added to your question would be ideal)

Comment: I've edited my question with more information.

Answer (score 0):

Is `sshd` service running on your guest OS? `qemu` just forward your package from `localhost:5555` to `guesthost:22`, if there is no `sshd` service listening on port 22 on your guest os, it will be `Connection reset by peer`.

Comment: Edited my question. `sshd` is running on my guest OS